# Visual studio: change reference paths?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, filepath, visual-studio-community

I am trying to build an old C# project in VS Community 2017 and receive the following error:

`C:\Users\shrout\source\repos\MyFirstNppPlugin\MyFirstNppPlugin\DllExport\NppPlugin.DllExport.targets : warning : Cannot find lib.exe in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\\..\..\VC\bin'.`

- Is there a method by which I can point VS 2017 to a different directory for lib.exe?
- If I create a `Community\VC\bin` directory and put `lib.exe` into it the build progresses past this point
- The lib.exe file I am using is currently located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\Hostx64\x64`

  - I would prefer to point VS at this directory instead of the one being referenced, but  don't know where to make that change.

**Extra Info:** I am trying to build a sample NotePad++ plugin from the following page:

[Sample Plugin from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip/download)

Comment: Thank you! Still green... Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, the reference is made from the `NppPlugin.DllExport.targets` file, which in turn is referenced from your project.

Given it's a project file and not a system-wide file, you can simply change the reference path in the `.targets` file.